# Angular 2 Typescript Setting a global property on the window object

Tags: typescript, angular

So I'm kinda new to Angular 2. Want to set up a global namespace by saying something like window.Dashboard. I have my main page loading and my jasmine tests loading, but my compiler watch keeps quitting and complaining saying "Property 'Dashboard' does not exist on type ‘Window'. Here is a pastebin. Anyone got any ideas on what im doing wrong? http://pastebin.com/DF9wXexH Thanks!!

```
//main.ts
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';

import { DashComponent } from './dash.component';


bootstrap(DashComponent);

//dash.component.ts

import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

interface Window {
    Dashboard?: any;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'main',
    template: '<h1>Welcome To The Dashboard</h1>'
})

export class DashComponent {
    constructor() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your interface you declare `Dashboard` as optional via the `?`.
I don't see any initialization of it. Without initialization it does not exist.
Get rid of the ? and/or initialize it. You also may want to rename the interface `IWindow` in order to avoid confusion with the global `window` object.